# Sql Select by using another table value(s)

Tags: sql, select

Basicly I have tables much like picture below.

[image]

At first I'm getting SaleOrderID by given CustomerID :

```
Select 
    SaleOrderID 
From tblSaleOrder  
where CustomerID = 512992
```

Which returns, 1002,1003,1005,1009

And I want to use that numbers for select from tblSaleOrderDetail :

```
Select 
    * 
from tblSaleOrderDetail 
where SaleOrderID = 1002,1003,1005,1009
```

(values from other query)

I need suggestion on query to use values from another select. Is there a way to create array to hold values then use it for another query ?  OR a easier  way !

Comment: If I were you I would look at `JOIN`, `IN`, and `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a subselect within an `in` clause:

```
select * 
from tblSaleOrderDetail 
where SaleOrderID in (
    select SaleOrderID
    from tblSaleOrder  
    where CustomerID = 512992)
```

When using a subselect within an in clause remember that you must only select one column within the subselect.

You could also perform a join:

```
   select *
   from tblSaleOrderDetail sod
   join tblSaleOrder so
   on sod.SaleOrderId = so.SaleOrderId
   where so.CustomerID = 512992
```

Comment: I think a simple JOIN could solve this with simpler SQL.

Comment: @JoeRinehart Like the join I demonstrate below in the second example.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very basic SQL operation, called the `join`.  Although you can use `in` for this purpose, the more typical way is:

```
select sod.*
from tblSaleOrder so join
     tblSaleOrderDetail sod
     on so.SaleOrderID = sod.SaleOrderID
where so.CustomerID = 512992;
```

If you are learning SQL, the `join` operation is one of the first things you should be learning.

Answer (score 1):

Probably going a bit overkill on this post since the question is fairly basic but I wanted to give you a list of options as well as some basic advice. One of the simplest ways to do this is by using the `IN` clause. The `IN` clause conceptually works a lot like = except it looks for a list of items.

Example

```
Select 
    * 
from tblSaleOrderDetail 
where SaleOrderID IN
    (
    Select 
        SaleOrderID 
    From tblSaleOrder  
    where CustomerID = 512992
    )
```

Yet another way to accomplish this is by using `EXISTS`. Which works very much like it sounds it checks for rows that exist in the other table.

```
Select 
    * 
from tblSaleOrderDetail AS SOD
where  EXISTS
    (
    Select 
        1 
    From tblSaleOrder  AS SO
    where CustomerID = 512992
    AND SOD.SaleOrderID = SO.SaleOrderID
    )
```

Notice how I use AS SO and SOD to give those tables new names. This is called aliasing and it is your friend. I highly recommend using it in you future queries.

You can use `JOIN` as well however when I started writing this there was already an example of this.